# ink.Save in C# take a long time and not working (how check malformed/incorrect data before feeding it to Ink )

Tags: c#, arrays, save

i want convert **strInkBase64** to **ink** and **ink** to **byte image**.

this my code:

```
    private byte[] ConvertInkToByte(string strInkBase64)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strInkBase64) || strInkBase64 == "AAUcA4CABA==\0")
        {
            return null;
        }
        UTF8Encoding uTF8Encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        Ink ink = new Ink();
        if (!strInkBase64.StartsWith("base64:"))
            strInkBase64 = "base64:" + strInkBase64;
        ink.Load(uTF8Encoding.GetBytes(strInkBase64));
        byte[] arrData= ink.Save(PersistenceFormat.Base64Gif, CompressionMode.Maximum);
        string s = Convert.ToBase64String(arrData);
        byte[] inkdata = Convert.FromBase64String(s);
       // Compress To Jpeg
        byte[] jpegData = ImageTools.CompressToJpeg(ImageTools.ByteArrayToImage(inkdata ), qualityJpegCompression);
        return jpegData;
    }
```

**Problem:**

Most of the times my code worked but **when length of strInkBase64 is *very large* or when strInkBase64 format is *incorrect* ink.Save take a long time and not working**. in this line :

```
  byte[] arrData= ink.Save(PersistenceFormat.Base64Gif, CompressionMode.Maximum);
```

i search in google but not found any solution for this.

please help me.

Comment: If you are stuck with the `Ink` class and cannot migrate away to alternative libraries, then you need to somehow detect malformed/incorrect data before feeding it to `Ink`. As you said, it's a MS class, so what could one do about it...?

Comment: i want check malformed/incorrect data before feeding it to Ink but i dont know how.

Comment: Okay, so, do you know how well-formed/correct data has to look like? Without knowing this its near impossible to detect incorrect data, right?